# git only clones sha for LFS files on Gitlab CI

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gitlab-ci, git-lfs

I pushed `.png` files, each of which is 2+MB file size and tracked by `git-lfs`, to my gitlab.com repository, say `repo_a`. In CI job on another repo `repo_b` where `git-lfs` is installed, repo_a is cloned. Now I see the size of all .png files are 132, which seems to be the same volume as `sha` output (as the following. Note: some values are populated for privacy):

```
$ git show HEAD:file-a.png | tee sha_temp
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:shashashaaaashashashaaaashashashaaaashashashaaaashashashaaaa
size 2430019
$ ls -l sha_temp 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 crookednoodle crookednoodle 132 Nov  7 05:35 sha_temp
```

However, On my computer instead on Gitlab CI, I can see the original files when I `git clone` the repo_a.

This makes me feel that the content of these files are still pointers, not the original files. I also noticed that on my computer, I see in the output the original files are downloaded like this:

```
Downloading file-a.png (2.5 MB)
```

But I don't see this in the output on CI job.

Obviously related, subsequent process that opens the images by OpenCV fails.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to solve (get around) the issue by myself. In the targeted repo, I modified the CI script to run `git lfs pull`.

Comment: did you find the cause of this behaviour? we observe similiar issue. Sometimes (not always) some png files are become pointers in working copies. We can fix this by removing this pointer files, and reverting this changes.